# Command line video conversion tools

Tags: linux, video, conversion, media

I'm looking into developing our video content platform and part of it includes a better way for our users to upload their video content (anything from dvds, flash video, dxid, wmv, etc..) and have it automatically converted, at the moment to mp4(h.264) so that they can use it on the site though our CMS.

So what im basically asking is: What is the best CLI tool for doing this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I use [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/)

It's open-source and cross platform, and used by a majority if not most of the existing encoders/converters out there.

Comment: Was just about to post it. +1

Comment: This is *The One*.  Many of the other tools are simply wrappers around ffmpeg, it's only downside is the complexity of options.

Comment: It's cross platform?  Is there a Windows build somewhere?

Comment: Download link available here: http://www.videohelp.com/tools/ffmpeg

Answer (score 1):

[MPlayer](http://www.mplayerhq.hu) comes with a tool called [MEncoder](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/DOCS/HTML/en/mencoder.html) that does decoding/encoding/recoding etc of videos. Free, open source & cross platform. It's essentially very similar to the already suggested [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/)

Answer (score 1):

[HandBrake](http://handbrake.fr/) has a pretty powerful command line interface, documented [here](http://trac.handbrake.fr/wiki/CLIGuide).

One advantage of this setup is that you can use the HandBrake GUI to configure presets and then just specify a preset name from the CLI to use that particular configuration, instead of having to specify a ton of command line arguments to configure the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

[Transcode](http://tcforge.berlios.de/)